# Merge two sound files into a new file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-cs5, flex4.6

How can merge two sounds and save as a new file?. One sound is a loaded mp3 file and the other from the microphone. Then I need to upload this sound into a server. Is this possible?

Comment: Who's Mike? :) ahh, it's microphone...

Answer (score 1):

This all can be done, but if you looking simple example with few methods to call, I'm afraid it's not so easy.

You can extract bytes from sound with [Sound.extract()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29). This data is sound amplitude in 16-bit numbers, right and left channel interleaved. Use ByteArray.readShort() to get them.

Microphone data can be captured with SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, [see example here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html). To mix them with song, just add sound amplitudes and write result into third array. The result will be essentially WAV-format (without header,) unpacked sound data. You can upload it raw, or search for "as3 mp3 encoder" (google), but these things are rare and written by entusiasts, so *maybe* you can get them work. Also, to mix sounds correctly, frequencies of data from mic and sound file must be equal.

And upload part - if this was file on disk, this would be easy - `FileReference.upload()`. But there's only data in memory. So you can look into [Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/CS5/AS3LR/flash/net/Socket.html) class to send it.